# Why is this regular expression match positive?

Tags: php, regex, posix-ere

Given the pattern `^[a-zA-Z0-9 .\-_]+$` and the string `te\\st`, why is the match positive? I'm using this to validate usernames and I don't want people to put slashes in their usernames, it messes with URLs.

I'm calling `ereg($pattern, $username)`, running PHP version 5.2.8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ereg` is crazy. I recommend avoiding it. You should try using [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/preg_match) for this:

```
$count = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 .\-_]+$/', 'te/\st', $matches);
print_r($matches); // empty array (no matches)
print $count; // 0 (no matches)
```

Answer (score 3):

`^[a-zA-Z0-9 ._-]+$`

Will work as well. To match a literal - in a character class it is usually safest to place it right before the ending ], or right after the opening [ when using ereg (POSIX). You should be able to escape out the - but for some reason when escaping it directly after the . seems to fail. Anyway there is a solution if you must use ereg. Really good question as to why that fails, the . should just be a normal character within the character class. Ereg is buggy.

[Further reference.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

And if you have the choice use preg (PCRE)...